# Wordpress - Visit custom post type post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have made a custom post type and made a function so it shows up on the main page.
This is my code:

```
function create_recipe_post_type() {
    $recipe_labels = array(
        'name'              => 'Recipes',
        'singular_name'     => 'Recipe',
        'menu_name'         => 'Recipes',
        'name_admin_bar'    => 'Recipe'
    );

    register_post_type( 'recipes',
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $recipe_labels,
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'post-formats',
                'author',
                'thumbnail',
                'excerpt',
                'comments'
            ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-carrot',
            'query_var' => 'recipes'
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_recipe_post_type' );

add_post_type_support( 'recipe_post_type', 'post-formats' );

// Add custom post type posts to main page
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_recipe_to_main_page' );

function add_recipe_to_main_page( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'recipes' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

Within the documentation I found that I can access the posts using

> single-{post-type}.php

but if I create a file called

> single-recipes.php

I still get the "Page Not Found" error.
Is there a way to fix this or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you have to go into permalink settings and change them from default to custom, and then save, then go back and change them to default again. Works for me when I have this problem

Comment: Haha it is wierd I know